# Generics partial specialization in Rust

Tags: generics, rust

Let's look at some example of mathematics vector. It consists of a different number of components depending on the space dimension.

- For 2D: x, y;
- For 3D: x, y, z;
- For 4D: x, y, z, w;
- Generic: N components.

In C++ I can use SFINAE concept to implement it.

```cpp
template <size_t D, typename T, typename = void>
struct Vector;

// Implement for 2D
template<size_t D, typename T>
struct Vector <D, T, std::enable_if_t<(D == 2)>>
{
    T x;
    T y;
}

// Implement for 3D
template<size_t D, typename T>
struct Vector <D, T, std::enable_if_t<(D == 3)>>
{
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
}
    
// Implement for 4D
template<size_t D, typename T>
struct Vector <D, T, std::enable_if_t<(D == 4)>>
{
    T x;
    T y;
    T z;
    T w;
}
```

How can I do the same in Rust?

Comment: We don't really have SFINAE in Rust. C++ templates are really a code generation mechanism masquerading as generics, whereas generics in... well, basically any other language, are a type system mechanism for parametric polymorphism. Someone with more experience in Rust may come along and find a way to hack it together, but certainly the idiomatic approach in Rust would be to use different structs (`Vector2`, `Vector3`, `Vector4`) and then place any common functionality in a trait (`trait Vector {...}`)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You cannot specialize generics in Rust like specializing templates in C++. (Rust has a feature called "specialization", but it only applies to `impl`s, and it's not really relevant here.) Rust generics are sometimes called "principled" because they have to work *in principle* (upon declaration), not just *in practice* (once instantiated). This is a **deliberate choice** on the part of Rust's designers to avoid some of the messier consequences of SFINAE in C++.

I can think of two main ways to achieve a similar effect to your C++ code in Rust, depending on the generic context of the code. One way is to use a trait as a type level function to compute the content type of a parameterized struct, which is similar to the C++ version but has slightly more verbose field access (for simplicity, I'll imagine that `T` is `f32` for these examples):

```
// types that contain the actual data
struct Vector2 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
}

struct Vector3 {
    x: f32,
    y: f32,
    z: f32,
}

// types that will be used to parameterize a type constructor
struct Fixed<const N: usize>;
struct Dynamic;

// a type level function that says what kind of data corresponds to what type
trait VectorSize {
    type Data;
}

impl VectorSize for Fixed<2> {
    type Data = Vector2;
}

impl VectorSize for Fixed<3> {
    type Data = Vector3;
}

impl VectorSize for Dynamic {
    type Data = Vec<f32>;
}

// pulling it all together
struct Vector<Z>(Z::Data) where Z: VectorSize;
```

Now, if you have `v: Vector<Fixed<2>>` you can use `v.0.x` or `v.0.y`, whereas if you have a `Vector<Dynamic>` you have to use `v.0[0]` and `v.0[1]`. But there's no way to write a generic function that uses `x` and `y` that will work with either `Vector<Fixed<2>>` or `Vector<Fixed<3>>`; since there's no semantic relationship between those `x`s and `y`s, that would be unprincipled.

Another option would be putting an array in `Vector` and making `x` and `y` convenience methods that access elements 0 and 1:

```
struct Vector<const N: usize> {
    xs: [f32; N],
}

impl<const N: usize> Vector<N> {
    fn x(&self) -> f32 where Self: SizeAtLeast<2> {
        self.xs[0]
    }

    fn y(&self) -> f32 where Self: SizeAtLeast<2> {
        self.xs[1]
    }
    
    fn z(&self) -> f32 where Self: SizeAtLeast<3> {
        self.xs[2]
    }
}

// In current Rust, you can't bound on properties of const generics, so you have
// to do something like this where you implement the trait for every relevant
// number. Macros can make this less tedious. In the future you should be able to
// simply add bounds on `N` to `x`, `y` and `z`.
trait SizeAtLeast<const N: usize> {}

impl SizeAtLeast<2> for Vector<2> {}
impl SizeAtLeast<2> for Vector<3> {}
impl SizeAtLeast<2> for Vector<4> {}

impl SizeAtLeast<3> for Vector<3> {}
impl SizeAtLeast<3> for Vector<4> {}
```

Now you can write generic functions that work for `Vector<N>` and use `x` and `y`, but it's not as easy to adapt this to allow mutation. One way to do so is to add `x_mut`, `y_mut` and `z_mut` methods that return `&mut f32`.

#### Related question

- [Equivalent of specific template usage in C++ for Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47675493/equivalent-of-specific-template-usage-in-c-for-rust)

Comment: Im very disappointed. I thought Rust supports SFINAE like a C++. Thank you very much for such detailed answers, you helped me a lot.

Comment: thanks for the info. With that in mind I could properly solve my structs design issue.

Answer (score 1):

Failing that, tuple types may become handy here. You could define the generic `Vector` struct below, which is aimed at taking a tuple type as the generic type argument:

```
struct Vector<T> {
   pub coord: T,
}

impl<T> Vector<T> {
   fn new(coord: T) -> Self {
      Self { coord }
   }
}
```

Then, as an example, if `(f32, f32)` is the type argument for `Vector`, you will obtain a two-dimensional vector:

```
let v2d /* : Vector<(f32,f32)> */ = Vector::new((1.0, 2.0)); value

println!("v2 = ({}, {})", v2d.coord.0, v2d.coord.1);
```

Similarly for three dimensions (i.e., `T = (f32, f32, f32)`):

```
type V3d = Vector<(f32, f32, f32)>;

let v3d = V3d::new((1.0, 2.0, 3.0));
```

...and so on.