# Can I do C++'s SFINAE in Rust?

Tags: rust

I was wondering about this code:

```
#[inline(always)]
pub fn multiply_u128<T>(a: T, b: T, result: &mut[u64])  {
    let r = a as u128 * b as u128;
    //fill result with 64 bit chunks
}
```

it will work for integers except when `T` is `u128`. In this case we could get overflows.
Is it possible to make this function work with `u8`, `u16`, `u32`, `u64` but not `u128`?

Comment: This code doesn't compile since the `as u128` cast doesn't work on generic types.

Comment: @Aplet123 yes I was thinking about restricting it too, it was just an example

Comment: Related, but more complex, and not directly an answer: [Generics partial specialization in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66832882/3650362)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Can I do C++'s SFINAE in Rust?

No, Rust's generics are resolved quite a bit differently than in C++.

---

The most suitable way to implement this would be with `Into<u64>`:

```
pub fn multiply_u128<T: Into<u64>>(a: T, b: T, result: &mut[u64])  {
    let r = a.into() as u128 * b.into() as u128;
    // fill result with 64 bit chunks
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a13748853f27b393d5b5db8df2c4d5f9). Also, if you're up to using nightly features, consider using [`u64::widening_mul`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.u64.html#method.widening_mul).

Answer (score 2):

You could introduce a trait for this purpose and only implement it for the relevant types.

```rust
pub trait NotBigUInt {
    fn as_u128(self) -> u128;
}

impl NotBigUInt for u8 {
    fn as_u128(self) -> u128 {
        self as u128
    }
}
impl NotBigUInt for u16 {
    fn as_u128(self) -> u128 {
        self as u128
    }
}
impl NotBigUInt for u32 {
    fn as_u128(self) -> u128 {
        self as u128
    }
}
impl NotBigUInt for u64 {
    fn as_u128(self) -> u128 {
        self as u128
    }
}

#[inline(always)]
pub fn multiply_u128<T: NotBigUInt>(
    a: T,
    b: T,
    result: &mut [u64],
) {
    let r = a.as_u128() * b.as_u128();
    //fill result with 64 bit chunks
    result[0] = r as u64;
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = [0_u64; 1];
    multiply_u128(1_u8, 1_u8, &mut r);
    multiply_u128(1_u16, 1_u16, &mut r);
    multiply_u128(1_u32, 1_u32, &mut r);
    multiply_u128(1_u64, 1_u64, &mut r);
    // multiply_u128(1_u128, 1_u128, &mut r);
}
```

Comment: Note that this can be made a lot less repetitive with a macro.

Comment: @Aplet123 certainly, but I find the solution easier to understand when explicitly applied to a few types. Of course, once understood, it can (should) be factorised.